# Pandas groupby to compute rolling sum over the next n-days

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
 print(df)
    
   dt_op_f      ID_FAR     cod_id   quantity    sales_next_days
  2019-01-12      10       1234        10        30 = 10+15+5    

  2019-01-13      10       1234        15        20 = 15+5       
  2019-01-13      3        1234         5        10 = 5+5

  2019-01-14      10        112         5         5
  2019-01-14      3        1234         5         5

  2019-01-15      10       1234         5         5
```

And for each combination of business ID ("ID_FAR") and product ID ("cod_id"), I would like to compute the sum of sales ("quantity") over the next n-days (with n equals to 7);

I tried with:

```
df.set_index('dt_op_f').groupby(['cod_id', "ID_FAR"]).rolling('7d', min_periods=1).quantity.sum()
```

But it only works with "past" n-days.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: you can  `shift` the result by 7 days and combine that with your dataframe. See https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pandas-dataframe-shift/

Comment: Thank you; Could you please translate the idea into code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can flip the index in the descending order and apply your rolling after:

```
df.set_index('dt_op_f').sort_index(ascending = False).groupby(['cod_id', "ID_FAR"]).rolling('7d', min_periods=1).quantity.sum().sort_index()
```

produces

```
cod_id  ID_FAR  dt_op_f   
112     10      2019-01-14     5.0
1234    3       2019-01-13    10.0
                2019-01-14     5.0
        10      2019-01-12    30.0
                2019-01-13    20.0
                2019-01-15     5.0
Name: quantity, dtype: float64
```