# How do I group by ID and 5 day periods, and sum?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, data-analysis

Find out the sale amount for each id
Day 1 to Day 4 i.e. Total sale amount in the first 4 days
Day 5  to Day 10 i.e. Total sale amount in the next 5 days and so on
Day 11 to Day 18
Day 19 to Day 28
Beyond Day 28 till date

What should I do next, how to select sum first 3 sale amounts together?

```
df.groupby(['ID','date']).sum()
```

```
output
ID                DATE
8259951          01/01/22   2000.0
                 02/01/22   1000.0
                 08/01/22   7000.0
                 09/01/22   4150.0
                 14/01/22   6000.0
... ... ...
148173081   31/01/22    150.0
148174131   31/01/22    100.0
148174601   31/01/22    1950.0
148174631   31/01/22    300.0
148175761   31/01/22    100.0
```

Comment: Related:[How to group DataFrame by a period of time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11073609/how-to-group-dataframe-by-a-period-of-time). [Pandas groupby to compute rolling sum over the next n-days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66586889/pandas-groupby-to-compute-rolling-sum-over-the-next-n-days)

Comment: First 3 sales per ID?